# connecting to SQL Server via PHP is failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo

I have a script that creates 2 connections to the database using PDO.

The first connection is made to a SQL Server and the second one is to MySQL.

The script was working fine until yesterday. I can't think of anything that could have changed. but the script now is failing

This is the exception that I am getting when trying to connect to SQL Server

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Invalid value 1 specified for option PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT.
```

I am running PHP 6.6 on Apache 2.4.12

I reviewed the script and the connection should be working with no issues.

This is my connection string

```
$connString = 'sqlsrv:Server=MyIP,1433;Database=MyDBname';

$pdo_opt[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
$pdo_opt[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE] = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC;

$pdo_opt[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND] = 'SET NAMES utf8';
$pdo_opt[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE] = true;

$pdo_opt[PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING] = PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8;

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($connString, $username, $password, $pdo_opt);
} catch(Exception $e){

    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

How can I correct this issue? or where should I start to investigate this issue?

Comment: where did you use `SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT`

Comment: Also, Same network or separate networks where the script is living and the SQL server is living. Any possibility someone shut down some posts when they noticed some SQL traffic flying through?

Comment: I fixed it by adding `$pdo_opt[PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT] = 30;` But why did it stop working all of the sudden?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I fixed it by adding this line of code

```
$pdo_opt[PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT] = 30;
```

Comment: Is it mean 30 seconds for 30 minutes?